# Валидация значений коллекции Bean Validation

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation

Не работает валидация значений коллекции HashSet. Валидация поля работает. Может на коллекции нельзя применять @Size?

```
@Entity
public class Order{

   @Size(max = 1000, message = "описание должно быть не более 1000 символов")
   @Column(length = 1000)
   private String description;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Column(name = "POSITION", length = 50)
    @Size(max = 50, message = "не более 50 символов")
    private Set<String> positions = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Comment: @Size в вашем случае будет проверять, истинность выражения positions.size < 50, то есть длину самой коллекции, но никак не длину элементов в ней.

Comment: и что, никак нельзя проверить длину элемента?

Comment: Можно, проверять что угодно, если создать свой валидатор, реализовав интерфейс ConstraintValidator. Или найти библиотеку, где это сделано. Стандартная же такого не предлагает.

Comment: понял, спасибо.